# Spring OpenID Google not working under Apache Proxy server

Tags: spring, spring-security, openid

Hi I am implementing spring security using openid under Apache mod proxy

```
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
```

where I proxy the tomcat url .The openid was working fine without proxy but with proxy spring OpenIDAuthenticationFilter sends **buildReturnToUrl** sends the tomcat url (localhost:8081) instead of proxy one .Even if I override this the other issue happens with the ConsumerManager verify method `verifyReturnTo(String receivingUrl, AuthSuccess response)`.

Is there any way to implement this instead of rewritng the whole of spring openid classes filter and consumerManager .

Let me know in case someone has solved this also if spring provides something to support such cases OOB as this is a common use case

Xml Config

```
<openid-login default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="openIdAuthFailureHandler"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" 
            >
            <attribute-exchange>
                <openid-attribute name="email"
                    type="http://axschema.org/contact/email" required="true" count="1" />
                <openid-attribute name="axContactEmail"
                    type="http://axschema.org/contact/email" required="true" />
                <openid-attribute name="oiContactEmail"
                    type="http://schema.openid.net/contact/email" required="true" />
                <openid-attribute name="axNamePersonFullname"
                    type="http://axschema.org/namePerson" required="true" />
                <openid-attribute name="axNamePersonFriendlyName"
                    type="http://axschema.org/namePerson/friendly" required="true" />
                <openid-attribute name="axNamePersonFirstName"
                    type="http://axschema.org/namePerson/first" required="true" />
                <openid-attribute name="axNamePersonLastName"
                    type="http://axschema.org/namePerson/last" required="true" />
            </attribute-exchange>
        </openid-login>
```

Regards